# React useState updated array not rendering

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, use-state

i am fetching realtime data from firebase and updating the data inside my useState variable whenever i receive that updated data.

The problem is that, the data inside the useState component gets updated but is not rendered unless i revisit the tab. I have tried every possible solution known to me but am not able to fix the issue.

Here is my code,

```
const blockItemsList: React.FC = () => {
    const [showLoading, setShowLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const [blockData, setblockData] = useState([]);
    const [isFirstTime, setFirstTime] = useState<boolean>(true);
  
    var currentData = [];
  
    const authTools = useAuth();
  
    const dataRef = db
      .collection("block")
      .doc(authTools.getUserId())
      .collection("details");
  
    function filterAndUpdateData(newData, deletedData, modifiedData) {
      var dataArr = currentData;
  
      newData.map((doc) => {
        dataArr.push(doc);
      });
  
      deletedData.map((doc) => {
        dataArr = dataArr.filter((item) => item.id !== doc.id);
      });
  
      modifiedData.map((doc) => {
        const index = dataArr.findIndex((element) => element.id === doc.id);
        dataArr[index] = doc;
      });
  
      dataArr.map((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.data());
      });
  
      setblockData(dataArr);
      currentData = dataArr
  
      if (isFirstTime) {
        setFirstTime(false);
        setShowLoading(false);
      }
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribe = dataRef.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        var newData = [];
        var deletedData = [];
        var modifiedData = [];
        const items = querySnapshot.docChanges().map((docObject) => {
          if (docObject.type === "modified") {
            modifiedData.push(docObject.doc);
          } else if (docObject.type === "added") {
            newData.push(docObject.doc);
          } else if (docObject.type === "removed") {
            deletedData.push(docObject.doc);
          }
        });
  
        console.log("AAH SHSIT");
        filterAndUpdateData(newData, deletedData, modifiedData);
  
        if (isFirstTime) {
          setFirstTime(false);
          setShowLoading(false);
        }
      });
  
      return () => unsubscribe();
    }, []);
  
    return (
      <>
        <IonPage>
              {!!blockData &&
                blockData.map((doc, index) => {
                  return (
                    <blockItem
                      key={doc.id}
                      num={index}
                      active={doc.data().health_status}
                      temperature={doc.data().temperature_faren}
                    />
                  );
                })}
        </IonPage>
      </>
    );
  };
```

Help would be greatly Appreciated.

Comment: What you're describing is called 'stale state.'  https://css-tricks.com/dealing-with-stale-props-and-states-in-reacts-functional-components/

Comment: Why do you manage added/updated/delete items? You could use `.onSnapshot` method and let firebase handle all this logic :/

Comment: @TomeuCabot apparently, firebase returns all the items the first time, and after that, in case of added items, it only returns added items, in case of modified itrems, it only returns modified items, and in case of deleted items, it only returns deleted items. So i have to update my application's data accordingly, else i wouldn't know whether the data that come from firebase was added, deleted or modified,

Comment: Calling doc (as first parameter on the callback function) `.data()` it should return all data, no? `.onSnapshot(data => setblockData(doc.data()));`

Comment: @JoelHager, Thank you very much, after following the article, my code successfully works.